# jQuery click event does not update ':last' when i add a new element that should become the new ":last"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i am having a small issue,
I am working on a small effect on jquery that works this way.
The user is provided with one input button.
as soon as he types something into the input field, a new input is added below it.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 data">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placehoder="some text"/>
        </div>                              
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="done"><span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var input_button = '<div class="col-md-4 data"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="some text"/></div>';
    var last = 'div.data input[type="text"]';
    $('div.data input[type="text"]:last').on("keyup",function(e)
    {
        value = $(this).val().trim();

        if(value.length != 0)
        {
            $('.row').append(input_button);
        }
    });
});
```

Therefore, i use the `$(div.data input[type="text"]:last)` selector and the `keyup` event.
However, in my own thinking, when i Add a new input button, it should automatically become the `":last"` input field. right?

But this is not the case. The last input field is, according to how the code is working, the first input field that originally existed?

Basically the first original input button is considered the "last" button even when more are added by the keyup event.

So my question is, how do i make the newly added input field (added using jquery) the last input field on the next keyup event?

Comment: Not related to your question. But instead of writing HTML in your JS. You can do something like this `var input_button = $('.data input[type=text]').last().clone().val('');`

Comment: Interesting. Does it increase on the loading of the input button?

Comment: Who downvoted all these answers? Every single answer has at least one downvote. It would have been helpful to explain why.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you bind to elements that are searched only once, not to a dynamic selector.

You should use

```
$('div.data').on("keyup", 'input[type="text"]:last', function(e)
```

so that the `'input[type="text"]:last'` selector is checked each time there's a `keyup` event in a descendant of an element of `$('div.data')`.

As your question isn't clear, in case you also dynamically add the `div.data` element, then you should do

```
$('.container').on("keyup", 'div.data input[type="text"]:last', function(e)
```

To read more about event delegation in jQuery, you can check [this page](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: Erm, I have no idea what difference that will make. Mind giving a small explanation of how different it is from what i had?

Comment: Well... I thought I had. Maybe it's clearer if you read the description of the "selector" argument in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ?

Comment: This binds to a specific input: $('div.data input[type="text"]:last').on when it runs, but this binds to the div and the input is dynamic: $('div.data').on

Comment: This will not work either, because the input is always last in each div.data
use this instead $('.row').on("keyup", 'input[type="text"]:last', function (e)

Answer (score 1):

When you dynamically create an element you have to select a parent element that is not being dynamically created then use the `on` function to trigger a function on an event.

So in your case you have to select a parent that is not being dynamically created which is `.row` and use the `on` function as follows:

```
$('.row').on("keyup", 'input[type="text"]:last', function (e)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/55SNt/

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality... that's probably because you haven't explained _why_ it answers the question. The best answers will always include some text as well as code.

Answer (score 0):

As the content are dynamically added on the fly , the event handler defined in your question points to the static field generated on page load. Instead you should do :

```
$(document).on("keyup", 'div.data input[type="text"]:last', function(e)
    {
        value = $(this).val().trim();
        if(value.length != 0)
        {
            $('.row').append(input_button);
        }
    });
```

here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UqHE7/).

See More about [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on, you have to consider what jQuery is doing:

```
//Your code:
$('div.data input[type="text"]:last').on("keyup", function(e) { 
   //...
});
```

It looks like one thing is happening there, but there are actually two:

- First you wrap the last element that matches `div.data input[type="text"]` in a jQuery object,
- Then you add a handler to it.

Once `$('div.data input[type="text"]:last')` runs, the element it contains isn't going to change. It's already been found. The event handler is operating on that specific element, not the position it occupies.

To fix this, you have to tell jQuery to bind the handler dynamically every time the event fires. Fortunately, the `on` method is clever about that, and gives you the option to do it differently:

```
$(document).on("keyup", 'div.data input[type="text"]:last', function(e) { 
   //...
});
```

This will search the entire document for `'div.data input[type="text"]:last'` before firing the event handler.

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it to work using your approach. I'm still having a hard time figuring out the difference between your way and my obviously incorrect approach

Comment: @JohnKariuki - Glad to hear it! If my answer was helpful, don't forget to mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, would you care to explain why?